# Why do $f$ and $f'$ generate all of $K[X]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, ideals

I have been studying Marcus' *Number Fields*. I am stuck on a remark in Appendix 2, page 258.

He says: A monic irreducible polynomial $f$ of degree n over $K$ (a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$) splits into n monic linear factors over $\mathbb{C}$. We claim these factors are distinct; any repeated factor would be a factor of the derivative $f'$. [This is clear to me.]

This is my question:

He says: But this is impossible since $f$ and $f'$ generate all of $K[X]$ as an ideal.

How would I know this $a$ $priori$?

He finishes using this saying $1$ is a linear combination of $f$ and $f'$ with coefficients in $K[X]$ to show $f$ and $f'$ have no common factors, etc., and thus $f$ has distinct roots in $\mathbb{C}$

I have no problem with the conclusion either. My only question is how to know $f$ and $f'$ generate all of $K[X]$ as an ideal.

Thanks as always for you help.

Comment: The proof of what happens in julien's answer can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#B.C3.A9zout.27s_identity and is pretty much just the Euclidean algorithm. Because you're working with polynomials you want something of minimal degree, not the smallest integer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Marcus says that $f$ is *irreducible*, so $(f,f')=1$. If not, then $f\mid f'$ (since the only non-constant divisor of $f$ is itself) and since $\deg f'<\deg f$ we have a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks what threw me was the line I mentioned as my question. What you said is sufficient, and one can go directly to your answer - which is equivalent to his remark.

Comment: @Andrew I'm curious what was the source of confusion. I read your question and comments, but I remain perplexed.

Comment: Aren't there fields $K$ such that $f\in K[X]$ is irreducible, but $f' = 0$? (For example $K = \mathbb{F}_p(T^p)$, $f = X^p - T^p$.)

Comment: @azimut Please read the question, especially the part about $K$ a subfield of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me to read the question. Basically, I just wanted to point out that irreducible alone is not enough. We don't know where the confusion came from, maybe he missed the fact $K < \mathbb{C}$. What is needed is irreducible & characteristic 0.

Comment: @MathGems Perhaps you would read my "Dear Julien" comment. Or to summarize: I knew the equivalence of Bezout, all of K[X], and no repeated roots. What I didn't know was how to get there. The implication of "irreducible" was what I failed to grasp. Admittedly something that I should have known.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for the explanation. That's what I eventually surmised was the most likely candidate. I'm always interested to learn about these things since they often indicate places where textbook expositions need improvement.

Comment: @MathGems My pleasure. I am a relatively new self-studier and well past my intellectual prime. Plus other than the generous help I get here I am on my own. I do find "Marcus" to be something I would really like to study. But I find I need to supply a lot from things I fortunately pick up elsewhere. E.g. on page 16 he just presents the matrix M, but if I had not seen the fuller linear algebra development elsewhere, I would have been stumped. But these types of issues may be somewhat unique to me, in that I am not well-schooled. Regards, Andrew

Comment: @MathGems Actually, I might give you a better example out of "Marcus." On p. 18-19 he says: For prime p the pth cyclotomic field contains a unique subfield of each degree dividing p - 1 [no problem]. Thus for each odd prime the pth cyclotomic field contains a unique quadratic field [still no problem]. This turns out to be Q [\sqrt{+/- p}]. Here I am stuck. He goes on to direct attention to Ex. 8. This entails the discriminant. But he doesn't get to that topic for five pages. So am I supposed to grasp this notion at this point in the text? Very frustrating.

Answer (score 12):

**Hint:** the gcd of $f$and  $f'$ is $1$ hence by Bezout, there exist $u,v\in K[X]$ such that
$$
uf+vf'=1.
$$

**Note:** if you know that the gcd remains the same in every extension (by Bezout and its converse, for instance), then you see directly that $gcd(f,f')=1$ in $\mathbb{C}[X]$. So $f$ can't have a repeated root. And you get a little shortcut.

Comment: That's my question. I mention what you said in my remarks. But this is not necessarily the case if there are multiple roots. As I tried (hopefully) to communicate, Marcus claims right off the bat that f and f' generate all of K[X]. Then he goes on to say what you mentioned based on that.

Comment: @Andrew The gcd remains the same in extensions. So the gcd of $f$ and $f'$ is $1$ in $\mathbb{C}[X]$. If there is a repeated root, then the gcd can't be $1$. Period. Marcus makes it more complicated than it is. Now if you really want to see why $f$ and $f'$ generate $K[X]$, just use Bezout to write $h=huf+hvf'$ for every $h\in K[X]$.

Comment: @Andrew Note that you've accepted the only answer out of four that does not address your question: how to prove that the ideal generated by $f$ and $f'$ is $K[X]$.

Comment: Dear Julien I appreciate your comment.  If I may say, I mentioned the use of Bezout - just not by name - and understand the equivalence of the linear combination being 1 and generating all of K[X]. My problem was how does one get to use that. What I missed was that "irreducible" implies that f and f' have no common factor. I apologise, but I did mention that I had no problem with:He finishes using this saying 1 is a linear combination of f and f′ with coefficients in K[X] to show f and f′ have no common factors, etc., and thus f has distinct roots in C.  Please accept my thanks.

Comment: P.S. I did +1 long ago. I can see did not articulate my question so as to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Andrew I see. So all is well, and everything must be clear for you now. And that's the most important. Take care.

Answer (score 6):

Consider $I = \langle f, f' \rangle = \langle g \rangle$ for some $g$, since $K[x]$ is a PID.  Since $g \mid f$ and $f$ is irreducible, $g$ is associate to (i.e., equal to up to multiplication by a unit) either $1$ or $f$.

Since $g \mid f'$ and (because the characteristic is zero!) $0 \leq \operatorname{deg} f' < \operatorname{deg} f$, we have $\operatorname{deg} g \leq \operatorname{deg} f' < \operatorname{deg} f$, so $g$ cannot be associate to $f$. Thus $g$ must be associate to $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $I = (f ,f')$ the ideal generated by $f$ and $f'$. It can be written $I = (P)$ with $P \in K[X]$ monic (since $K[X]$ is principal). Clearly, $(f) \subset I$ so $P | f$. And because $f$ is irreducible, we get either $P = 1$ of $P = f$. But clearly $f' \notin (f)$, so $P = 1$.